# How to update a value from other tables in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

currently I have 3 tables

Table 1:

| tb1_id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |

Table 2:

| tb1_id | tbl3_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

Table 3:

| tb3_id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 2 |

For some reason the values from table 1 are not the same in table 3 (as shown above), I need to update the values of the table 1 with the table 3, but I am not able to do so, so far this is my query:

```
UPDATE
    table1 t1
SET 
    values =  temp_tbl.values
FROM 
    (
        SELECT t2.tb1_id, t3.values FROM table2 t2
        JOIN 
        table3 t3 ON t2.tbl3_id = t3.tbl3_id
    ) temp_tbl
WHERE 
      t1.tbl1_id = temp_tbl.tbl1_id
AND
    t1.values != temp_tbl.values;
```

Comment: You have misspelled `temp_tbl` in the `where` clause.  So if you are getting an error, that might explain it.

Comment: Are you sure that they should be same? Maybe you need to share real world data before overwriting and risking losing it. If they need to be then explain why (table and) Id should be different

Comment: @GordonLinoff The spell error was mine, the real statement does not have those errors

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yes, they should be the same, each table have other columns, but for the problem I am facing those are the columns I care about

Comment: @Said . . . Your code looks correct.  You may have inadvertently fixed it when putting it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so if I understood you correctly, you just need to make a slight correction to your code:

```
UPDATE
    table1 t1
SET 
    values =  temp_tbl.values
FROM 
    (
        SELECT t2.tbl1_id, t3.values 
        FROM table2 t2
        Inner JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.tbl3_id = t3.tbl3_id
    ) temp_tbl
WHERE 
      t1.tbl1_id = temp_tbl.tbl1_id
AND
    t1.values != temp_tbl.values;
```

Here is [DBFiddle link.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=638803c30b72976e23729ba65569ea6b)

EDIT: This would also do:

```
with newData as (
   select t1.tbl1_id, t3.Values
   from Table1 t1
   inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Tbl1_Id = t2.Tbl1_Id
   inner join Table3 t3 on t2.Tbl3_Id = t3.Tbl3_Id
   where t1.Values != t3.Values
)
UPDATE
    table1
SET 
    values = newData.Values
FROM newData 
where table1.tbl1_id = newData.tbl1_id;
```

Comment: What is the slight correction?  You might want to explain that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, you could see it yourself:( Field names were not right.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can do it:

-- temporary tables

```
SELECT 1 TBL1_ID, 4 valuet1 INTO #t1

SELECT 1 TBL1_ID, 5 TBL3_Id INTO #t2

SELECT 5 TBL3_ID, 2 valuet3 INTO #t3
```

-- select with joins

```
select T1.*,T2.*, T3.*
from #t1 T1
INNER JOIN #t2 T2
    ON T1.TBL1_ID = T2.TBL1_ID
INNER JOIN #t3 T3
    ON T3.TBL3_ID = T2.TBL3_ID
```

-- update would be like this

```
update #t1 set valuet1 = T3.valuet3
from #t1 T1
INNER JOIN #t2 T2
    ON T1.TBL1_ID = T2.TBL1_ID
INNER JOIN #t3 T3
    ON T3.TBL3_ID = T2.TBL3_ID
```